# Loop through a nested dictionary and get its path

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object with the following structure:

```
source = {
"org_name": "root",
"orgs": [
    {
        "org_name": "alpha1",
        "orgs": []
    },
    {
        "org_name": "alpha2",
        "orgs": [
            {
                "org_name": "beta1",
                "orgs": [
                    {
                        "org_name": "gama1",
                        "orgs": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to parse this JSON and add a key named org_path which contains the path of the orgs
the output should be like this

```
source = {
"org_name": "root",
"org_path": "root"
"orgs": [
    {
        "org_name": "alpha1",
        "org_path": "root/alpha1"
        "orgs": []
    },
    {
        "org_name": "alpha2",
        "org_path": "root/alpha2"
        "orgs": [
            {
                "org_name": "beta1",
                "org_path": "root/alpha2/beta1"
                "orgs": [
                    {
                        "org_name": "gama1",
                        "org_path": "root/alpha2/gama1"
                        "orgs": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am having a hard time finding a logic to get a output.

Comment: What code have you tried with?

Comment: I'd suggest using a recursion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Comment: Shouldn't `"beta1"` have `"root/alpha2/beta1"`? And `"gama1"` have `"root/alpha2/beta1/gama1"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
def add_path_to_dict(dictionary, path=""):
    path += dictionary["org_name"]
    dictionary["org_path"] = path
    path +="/"
    for orgs in dictionary["orgs"]:
        orgs = add_path_to_dict(orgs, path)
    return dictionary


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(add_path_to_dict(source))
```

Comment: `if dictionary["orgs"] != []` check is unnecessary, it will skip the loop if the `dictionary["orgs"]` is empy. `enumerate` is unnecessary, you can use `orgs` instead of `dictionary["orgs"][i]`. This will also add `"/"` to the root (`'/root'`). `iteration` is not a very descriptive name for the function.

Comment: Yeah indeed, added your suggestions